# How to separate partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I need partitions separated. I am trying to install Windows:

[image: picture of Windows installation screen]

How can we separate this partition so he can install Windows?

Comment: Where is his old data stored? Does he have a proper external backup?

Comment: No he dosent have a backup @DavidPostill

Comment: The major concern now is downloading Windows @DavidPostill im sure thier is like a partion recovery

Comment: So his data is on this disk? How did he lose it? You need to be very clear in your question about what happened to have any change of recovering anything.

Comment: @DavidPostill i deleted the logical drive partion , and then now he installed windows 10 on another computer, to his USB. Now he is booting it up from his USB . After he does, he is faced with this option. Right now im trying to ask you guys how can he install windows because he has one partion , and as you can see it says Windows cant be installed on drive 0 partion 1 .

Comment: @DavidPostill right now we dont really care about data because we can Use EASEUS : http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery-software/recover-lost-partition-windows-10.html , to recover it.. Right now we have to install windows.

Comment: That would be taking chances. Data recovery comes in as a last resort..and doesn't replace proper backup procedure. If you're not bothered about the data, or have appropriate backups, simply delete the partition using the setup page, and then click `New` and define the partition sizes. **Warning!!** Deleting the partition would wipe out all the data. For screenshots check out [this page](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/clean-install-Windows-10/)

Comment: @Dsafds - if you think you first need to install Windows, THEN try to recover data... you are about to fail in the 2nd & more important task in a major & irretrievable way. Overwriting your damaged site is really not the way to go about data recovery - that's the equivalent of emptying the gas tank because the car's too heavy :/

Comment: @Tetsujin that is EXACTLY what im trying to do look at my third comment

Comment: @Dsafds - then stop right now. You need recovery, not further damage.

Comment: @Tetsujin not me, but what do you mean recovery?

Comment: From your own comment "right now we dont really care about data because we can Use EASEUS "... so you need to recover data? if you need to recover data... **stop what you are doing now** & instead move to *recovering data*. Or alternatively, forget the data & continue trying to install an OS on that drive. Your call.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, if you install windows over that hard drive, you will overwrite the contents of that drive.

You MAY be able to use recovery software to retrieve your files, but it is an unnecessary risk. Standard practice when wanting to save data when installing a new OS is to put it onto an external backup, run  your install, then transfer data back over. You mention you have a usb stick, that's a good start. You don't need to save everything, only what you want.

The reason you are getting "Unable to install on Drive 0 Partition 1" is because Windows uses the free space on a hard drive to create multiple partitions.
If you have no free space, it is unable to do this. FYI the partitions are a ~500MB system partition, a small recovery partition, then the rest is for you to use.

You can shrink partitions depending on the version of windows. To do so:

- Boot into normal windows (Not your USB ran windows 10)
- Press Win+R to open run menu
- Type "diskmgmt.msc" Right click your partition, and
  click Shrink volume. Enter the amount to shrink by (needs to be atleast 16GB)

  Give yourself enough free space to install windows (Windows 10 needs 16GB minimum) You can then use this free space to create the partitions Windows 10 needs at setup. Note that if you don't have that much unused space on your disk, you may loose files or it may not let you do it.